# Problem opening .sh files

Tags: .sh

I'm trying to install netbeans-7.4-linux.sh on my 13.10 Ubuntu.

After using terminal `sudo sh ./netbeans-7.4-linux.sh` it is telling me `cannot open netbeans-7.4-linux.sh`.

How do I get past this?

Comment: This is probably a permissions issue. Do you know how permissions work?

Comment: Can you paste the **exact** error that you get when you try to execute it to your question?

Comment: Can root access that file? Maybe the file is in your encrypted home directory?

Comment: just remove ./ before the netbeans-.... so the command is like that `sudo sh netbeans-7.4-linux.sh`

Answer (score 0):

#### Force a script to run

1. `sudo bash /path/to/file.sh`

#### Setting a file for execution

1. `chmod +x /path/to/file.sh`
2. `./path/to/file.sh

#### Problems with symbolic links

1. echo "set mark-symlinked-directories on" >> ~/.inputrc
2. `./path/to/file.sh